# How to insert code verbatim into SWIG interface?

Tags: common-lisp, swig, cffi

I need to insert code into the header of the generated file, but the inserted code is written in Lisp. Since SWIG tries to parse it, it breaks.  I need something analogous to `%pythoncode` command, but for CFFI (Lisp).

```
#ifdef SWIGCFFI

%begin
%{
    (in-package :some-package)
%}
#endif /* SWIGCFFI */
```

Also, looking at this: https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Source/Modules/cffi.cxx#L140 am I right to assume that the contents of `%begin` will be thrown away unless `CPlusPlus || CWrap` is true? (but I don't need C wrapper and the API is for C, not C++)?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my onw question:

```
%insert("lisphead") %{
    (in-package :some-package)
%}
```

This appears to be the way to do it. Thanks this blog post: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-swig-insert-directive.html